# How to stop sending to kafka topic when control goes to catch block Functional kafka spring

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

could you please advise , how can I stop sending to my 3rd kafka topic, when the control reaches the catch block, currently the message is sent to both error topic as well as the topic to which it should send in case of normal processing. A snippet of code is as below:

```
@Component
public class Abc {
private final StreamBridge streamBridge;
public Abc (StreamBridge streamBridge)
this.streamBridge = streamBridge;
@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, KafkaClass>, KStream<String,KafkaClass>> hiProcess() {
return input -> input.map((key,value) -> {
try{
KafkaClass stream = processFunction();
}
catch(Exception e) {
Message<KakfaClass> mess = MessageBuilder.withPayload(value).build();
streamBridge.send("errProcess-out-0". mess);
}
return new KeyValue<>(key, stream);
})
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be implemented using the following pattern:

```
KafkaClass stream;
return input -> input
    .branch((k, v) -> {
        try {
            stream = processFunction();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Message<KakfaClass> mess = MessageBuilder.withPayload(value).build();
            streamBridge.send("errProcess-out-0". mess);
            return false;
        }
       },
       (k, v) -> true)[0]
    .map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<>(k, stream));
```

Here, we are using the branching feature (API) of `KStream` to split your input into two paths - normal flow and the one causing the errors. This is accomplished by providing two filters to the `branch` method call. The first filter is the normal flow in which you call the `processFunction` method and get a response back. If we don't get an exception, the filter returns `true`, and the result of the branch operation is captured in the first element of the output array `[0]` which is processed downstream in the `map` operation in which it sends the final result to the outbound topic.

On the other hand, if it throws an exception, it sends whatever is necessary to the error topic using `StreamBridge` and the filter returns `false`. Since the downstream `map` operation is only performed on the first element of the array from branching `[0]`, nothing will be sent outbound. When the first filter returns `false`, it goes to the second filter which always returns `true`. This is a no-op filter where the results are completely ignored.

One downside of this particular implementation is that you need to store the response from `processFunction` in an instance field and then mutate on each incoming `KStream` record so that you can access its value in the final `map` method where you send the output. However, for this particular use case, this may not be an issue.

Comment: This is great. Thank you v much!!

Comment: @sobychacko, i am using the same code as above in Kafka 3.0.0 and getting "Broker may not be available".

Comment: Could you create a [minimal-sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can verify?

Comment: @sobychacko, i am able to resolve this problem by configuring the Spring producer settings ie. cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration etc. is there any better way we can send the error message to error Topic in Spring cloud stream? ie Processor