# Multiple Output Bindings (AKA Branching) In Spring Cloud Stream With Different Key/Value

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I know Kafka Streams allow data to be distributed to multiple topics based on specified predicates, and the Kafka Streams binder supports this using both the `@StreamListener` and the `functional binding` approach.

```
...
// return type KStream<?, WordCount>[]

Predicate<Object, WordCount> isEnglish = (k, v) -> v.word.equals("english");
Predicate<Object, WordCount> isFrench =  (k, v) -> v.word.equals("french");
Predicate<Object, WordCount> isSpanish = (k, v) -> v.word.equals("spanish");

return input.
    ... 
    branch(isEnglish, isFrench, isSpanish);
```

I'm wondering how to transform either the key or value of one of the branches before returning the data. Say I'd like one of the branches to have a different key type from the others.

```
Predicate<Key, Value> isOne = (k, v) -> v.important.equals("1");
Predicate<Key, Value> isTwo =  (k, v) -> v.important.equals("2");

KStream<Key, Value>[] branches = input.branch(isOne, isTwo);

KStream<String, Value> one = branches[0].selectKey((k, v) -> v.importantValue);
```

I thought of creating a new `KStream<?, Value>[]` array with both streams but couldn't because of the generic array creation error.

I know this is possible as could be seen from the documentation excerpt below, different key/value serdes could be specified for each branch's `producer`.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.output1.producer.valueSerde=IntegerSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.output2.producer.valueSerde=StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.output3.producer.valueSerde=JsonSerde
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Are you asking only about change the key serializer? Then is just use `...producer.keySerde=`. Or do you want to know how to configure the branch with different annotation?

Comment: `I'm wondering how to transform either the key or value of one of the branches before returning the data.` did you try to use a `.map` transformation?

Comment: @Felipe `.map` will work in transforming any of the branches but the question is how to actually return all the transformations (branches) in the KStream array for binding

Comment: I guess you are using this example (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-branching/src/main/java/kafka/streams/branching/KafkaStreamsBranchingSample.java), arent you? So, if I understood correct you want to transform only events with respect to a specific filter predicate, but return both streams in the end to the branches. The filtered stream that you transformed and the non-filtered stream that you don't want to transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a side topic. Then, every record that is different from the `WordCount` you send to that side topic. Records that are still a `WordCount` you keep on the topics of the branches.

I create this example of code based on the samples of [Spring cloud streams with KStream](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-branching/src/main/java/kafka/streams/branching/KafkaStreamsBranchingSample.java). It is not working because but the idea works. I have one simular example which consumes different `Order` objects and send wrong `Orders` to an error topic.

```
return input -> {
            KStream<?, WordCount> intermediateStream = input
                    .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+")))
                    .groupBy((key, value) -> value)
                    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(6)))
                    .count(Materialized.as("WordCounts-1"))
                    .toStream()
                    .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(null,
                            new WordCount(key.key(), value, new Date(key.window().start()), new Date(key.window().end()))));

            // here we return to the SIDE_TOPIC records with JsonSerde
            intermediateStream
                    .filter((k, v) -> `create another filter`)
                    .map((k, v) -> `transform only this stream`)
                    .to(SIDE_TOPIC, Produced.with(CustomSerdes.String(), new JsonSerde(....)));

            // here we keep using the branch serializer.
            intermediateStream.branch(isEnglish, isFrench, isSpanish);
        }
```

This use case is a common approach when you consume data that comes with error or null values that you want to send to a side topic, i.e.: an error topic. Then you can still save those events to analyze them in the future.

Comment: Hi, sending the error records can be addressed using a different pattern. See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66749750/2070861